# How to bind a query result in flex 4.5 using a data service - PHP/mySQL/Flex 4.5

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am trying to bind a variable with the results of a query performed thru the PHP script below:

```
<?php

//conection info
define("DATABASE_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DATABASE_PORT", "3306");
define("DATABASE_USERNAME", "root");
define("DATABASE_PASSWORD", "root");
define("DATABASE_NAME", "e5001");

class EsporteService
{
    private $_pdo;

    public function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.DATABASE_SERVER.';port='.DATABASE_PORT.';dbname='.DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD);

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            throw($e);
        }
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @return array[Esporte]
     */
    public function getEsportes()
    {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM esporte_tb';            
        $stmt = $this->_pdo->query($query);
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,'Esporte');
    }
}
```

And the mxml piece is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:consultaservice="services.consultaservice.*"
        xmlns:esporteservice="services.esporteservice.*"
        title="HomeView" creationComplete="view1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>

        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function view1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                getEsportesResult.token = esporteService.getEsportes();
            }

        ]]>
        </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:CallResponder id="getEsportesResult"/>
        <esporteservice:EsporteService id="esporteService"/>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:VGroup x="10" y="10" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center">
        <s:Image x="100" width="179" height="125" source="assets/spadotto_logo.jpg"/>
        <s:List id="list" height="40%" 
                dataProvider="{getEsportesResult.lastResult}"
                labelField="esp_desc"
                change="navigator.pushView(TreinosDetails, list.selectedItem)"/>
        <s:Label id="teste" />

    </s:VGroup>
</s:View>
```

I tried a lot of different ways, creating a bindable variable as Array, ArrayCollection, Object, etc, but was not able to make it work.

I am trying to parse the query and get the length of it, based on that the label "teste" will be visible or not.

Any ideas?

Many thanks,

Gines

Comment: It looks all quiet unnecessarily complicated, but I would suggest to answer it within Php and then send it back to FLEX using Xml within the Php file as you would do in reading & writing working with MySQL databases. In your case it would just be only one text field which is necessary in FLEX as a answer field!. regards aktell

Comment: Your code looks good to me. You should try looking at it in the debugger. However, what you may want to do is to try doing a asynchronous call.